# How should I study 'Linear Algebra'?

Tags: linear-algebra, self-learning

I study with Friedberg's Linear Algebra 4th edition.

I'm hesitating for my way to study linear algebra.

Should I try to solve all problems in textbook or some choosen problems?

Please give me an advise.

Thank you.

- I major in physics and I also interested in mathematics. I want to build bases for my later learning physics and mathematics.

Comment: What is your goal? Why do you need to study L.A.? Are you preparing tests or not? You might add these information to your question so we can give some on-point advice.

Comment: @xbh people who are just about to study LA rarely know why to study it. It is after maybe 3rd or 4th year they realize how incredibly useful it is when they seen it come up in like 20-30 courses.

Comment: It's as with many things in life, if you don't know it then you don't know what you miss out on. If you know it then new possibilities open up for you.

Comment: @mathreadler Sorry. I did not mean that. The reason clearly would be obscure for now. I just want to ask more information from the OP. Sorry again for confusion.